# JavaScript + Reference object in another function?

Tags: javascript

If I create an object in an onLoad function, then attempt to reference that object within an onChange function, the object is 'undefined'... how do I reference it?

**HTML:**

```
<body onLoad="loaded()">
    <select onChange="updateObject(event)">
        <option value="v1">--v1--</option>        
        <option value="v2">--v2--</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

**JS:**

```
function loaded(){             
    var obj = new ObjectExample();
}
function updateObject(event){
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are dealing with here is variable scope. The object 'obj' only exists within the 'loaded' function as that is where it is declared. A quick and easy way to solve this problem is to give the variable a larger scope. Eg, a global scope.

```
var obj;

function loaded(){                  
    obj = new ObjectExample(); 
} 
function updateObject(event){     
    console.log(obj); 
}
```

The 'obj' variable now exists on the 'window' object (try typing in window.obj in your browser console tool!).

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj;

function loaded(){             
    obj = new ObjectExample();
}
function updateObject(event){
    console.log(obj);
}
```